# Как правильно заполнить двумерный массив на PHP?

Tags: php

Задача сформировать двумерный массив товаров, которые я получил, когда парсил страницу (там цена, ссылка, название товара).

Нужно, чтобы можно было получить конкретный Элемент.
Допустим `$Goods[1]['Cost']` — стоимость.

Не знаю, что я не так делаю, в общем не выводится он...

```
$Goods=Array();

// Шаблон   для   парсинга Цены
$pattern='#<span class="value">US \$(?<Cost>\d{1,}.\d{1,})</span>#Ui';

$m = ( preg_match_all($pattern,$wholefile,$matches) ); //возвращает кол-во всех!  совпадений,

if($m) {//если есть совпадения
    $podmassiv=$matches['Cost'];//Возвращает массив из элементов чисел
    //echo $m;
    for($j=0;$j<$m;$j++){//до 36
        echo $podmassiv[$j] .'<br />';
        //Формирование Массива товаров-в каждом товаре своя цена
        foreach($Goods as $good =>$massiv) {
            foreach($massiv as $inner_key =>$value) {
                $Goods[$good][$inner_key] = $podmassiv[$j].'<br />';
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $Goods[1]['Cost'] . "ну чего ты не делаешься";
```

Comment: А можно содержимое $wholefile привести?
Только обязательно с корректным синтаксисом. 
А то в предыдущем вопросе у вас там тэг title закрывается раньше положенного. 


Comment: там содержится весь html-код страницы, наверно много тогда будет тут)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конструкция foreach перебирает массив,а не создает, как видно в первой стороке у вас массив $Goods пуст, по этому и перебирать нечего.)
Если вы хотите присвоить массиву резултат функции `preg_match_all`:

```
$Goods=Array();
$reg='#<span class="value">US \$(?<Cost>\d{1,}.\d{1,})</span>#Ui';
if($m=preg_match_all($reg,$wholefile,$matches))
{
    for($i=0;$i<$m;$i++)
    {
        $Goods[$i]['Cost']=$matches['Cost'][$i];
    }
}
```

Более относительно Вашего регулярного выражения не вытащить.

Для сортировки пригодится следующая конструкция:

```
if(!function_exists("sortArrayAnswer"))
{
    function sortArrayAnswer($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a < $b) { return 1; } elseif ($a == $b) { return 0; } else { return -1; }
    }
}
usort($a,'sortArrayAnswer');
```

Где $a ваш массив в котором нужно отсортировать числа по убыванию

Comment: спасибо, а как теперь отсортировать весь массив по Цене, то есть там есть цена, ссылка, название товара, мне нужно чтобы выводилось по возрастанию цены.если просто делать sort($Goods), то результаты неправильные что-то, по-моему из-за того что он по алфавиту еще сравнивает ссылки и название...